# Including instance specific data (e.g. result of toString()) in SLF4J format

Tags: java, logging, slf4j

I have a lot of method calls that look like this:

```
log.info("{}: Initiated", this);
```

when I would rather they just looked like this:

```
log.info("Initiated");
```

while still letting me know which instance logged the event and not just the class. If I create a convenience method  I lose location information, i.e. the logs show that the calling method is the convenience method and not the method from which it was called.

I considered extending `LoggerWrapper` but I still have to override a lot of methods and it seems like overkill for such a simple use case. It would also lead to an individual logger for each instance which seems like notable overhead.

An MDC seems close to what I want but as I understand it it only shows specific information for each thread, not for objects.

I feel like I'm missing something. Is there an easy way to do this? Isn't this a common requirement?

Comment: What logging library are you using? logback?

Comment: @assylias I'm using SLF4J since everyone seems to find it amazing. I've only just started using it and the specific backend library can easily be swapped. So I can be using logback behind the scenes if necessary. However I feel that I can't be alone in wanting this simple feature so a solution independent of the underlying framework is preferable.

Comment: You could give each instance its own logger (e.g. by appending a number to the logger name).

Comment: I would expect the solution to be in the logging framework, possibly in the form of a pattern or a custom logger.

Comment: @Henry like I said in the question, a logger per instance seems like unnecessary overhead - I'm essentially doubling the number of objects I use. Moreover how do I create this logger? Do I have to override every method of the `LoggerWrapper` class? There's 61 if I'm counting correctly.

Comment: @AlexHall logger creation is easy, no code changes necessary: there is a `LoggerFactory.getLogger` method taking a string argument. Just make sure to use an instance specific logger name.

Comment: @Henry oh I see what you mean. That'll work in some cases but the name is static and so the example case that I gave where the message contains `this.toString()` won't work if `toString` references mutable fields.